# ScriptResource.axd vulnerable script when I test it with Shadow Security Scanner

Tags: asp.net, ajax, security

I was performed tests againts my web server using Shadow Security Scanner with the following results:

Web Servers : Vulnerable script 
Port : 80
Description: Found vulnerable script on this web site
Risk level :High
Script: http://servername/ScriptResource.axd?d=P4tzN-eCJlchxi30M7K6eGzyH7tdeY4timDGCw0yDS45Ur477KM8CSqJQdqun4VDGbs5xXGPE7VeqXqRIDyOHxwoopCbgbWmKFLiyKB1Qs5UDJTyZQYe4zURSEshSBwPOm1hORh40237AJZ_EWO2n2-3IwAzTY__px0r6WbIYgWamkVz0&t=/etc/passwd
CVE : GENERIC-MAP-NOMATCH

Why ScriptResource.axd is a vulnerable script?

Thanks in advance.

Don Pablone

Comment: On a side note,  try another tool like https://sitewat.ch/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automated tools will produce false positives.  Have you tried to manually verify this vulnerability?      Judging by this PoC its supposed to print out the /etc/passwd file (or possibly overwritten its not clear).   However this file is *nix only,  so it shouldn't exist on your system.  You could try setting the t variable to a file that does exist:
../../../../../../../../../Windows/system.ini

If its not being printed out then its a false positive.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rook. I was trying your suggestion and the result is the same that I had when I set the t variable to 'web.config'. The browser prints the source code of MicrosoftAjax.debug.js file. I agree with you, is a false positive vulnerability. Thanks again.